# PHP 7.0.2/3 script crashes when using pthreads 3.1.4

Tags: php, pthreads

I was given some pieces from working project code: http://pastebin.com/Gj0YHbGU
The problem is that it crashes very often for no reason. Here's what it says:

```
Can't initialize heap: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.

Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 7.0.2.0, time stamp: 0x568d8186
Faulting module name: php7ts.dll, version: 7.0.2.0, time stamp: 0x568d8ca4
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000016f2b
Faulting process id: 0x1098
Faulting application start time: 0x01d16b4f0904a1f0
Faulting application path: C:\php7\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\php7\php7ts.dll
Report Id: f28545f0-d742-11e5-9e7b-fe884bd313a5
```

php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 3000M
extension=php_pthreads.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Also, server runs on windows 2008.
Script code looks like fine but nevertheless it still crashes. Why is this happening?

Pthreads v 3.1.6, same error message:

```
Can't initialize heap: [0x000001e7] Attempt to access invalid address.
```

windows crash report:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: php.exe
  Application Version:  7.0.2.0
  Application Timestamp:    568d8186
  Fault Module Name:    php7ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   568d8ca4
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000016f2b
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.1296.17
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a597
  Additional Information 2: a597d1d8df0aae8b1608dbb877a67057
  Additional Information 3: 715e
  Additional Information 4: 715efb3ccb937560161d6e308777a8b5
```

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of pthreads ?

Comment: @JoeWatkins, okay I'll test it and will write results.

Comment: @JoeWatkins, I tried with latest version and got same crash. Updated topic with crash report.

Comment: The code has external dependencies, I can't debug it. Reduce the problem to the simplest possible code ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins, got it.

Comment: I doubt it's "for no reason".